# Can I remove a Hard Drive with Windows 7 and transfer it to the same model computer without problems?

Tags: transfer

I want to order a spare computer with the same model as the current PC. If the power supply dies on the orginial computer, I would like to switch it to the other PC.  This has worked for me with Windows XP. There is no encryption on the Hard Drive.  Has anyone tried this before, and if so what problems have you had?

Comment: I have done this before without any issue. You shouldn't have a problem unless the systems are drastically different.

Comment: The make, model and speed of RAM, Motherboard, processor, GPU, BIOS, etc. have to be the same. Slight differences may cause short periods of non-responsiveness, or some system failures.

Answer (score 1):

If it is the **EXACT** same model then you will experience ZERO issues.

If the model number is off by just one character then you might simply have to re-install a driver or two.

> CompX Pterodactyl 2500-khul39j

▲ Would have at least one piece of different hardware than ▼

> CompX Pterodactyl 2500-khul39o

It usually signals something minor such as a different LAN controller on the motherboard like Intel vs Marvell

Honestly, as long as the motherboard is the same relative model then the issues should be either minuscule or non-existent.

Answer (score 0):

In my past job, we were doing this when the computer die but the hardrive was ok.
if it's exacly the same hardware should work.

we where using hp xw4600.