# Windows 7 Ready to use system image

Tags: windows, backup, disk-image

Good day,

I want to create a dvd of my windows 7 with installed programs.

I have a new windows 7 with a few standard programs installed. (Photoshop, Office, etc.) How can i make an image on a dvd of usb. So that my colleague just can format his hard drive and use my windows image for installation so he already had Photoshop, office, notepad++ etc installed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Computer refresh - Efficiently cloning 60 indentical computers](http://superuser.com/questions/277135/computer-refresh-efficiently-cloning-60-indentical-computers)

Comment: Does your colleague have the exact same computer as you? **[Kind of related answer here](http://superuser.com/questions/730859/can-i-remove-a-hard-drive-with-windows-7-and-transfer-it-to-the-same-model-compu/730877#730877)**

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of guides for that.

Two that stand out are:

**Lifehacker**: [How to Create a Custom Windows Installation DVD or USB Install](http://lifehacker.com/5793427/how-to-create-a-custom-windows-installation-dvd-or-usb-install)

**HowToGeek**: [How To Create a Customized Windows 7 Installation Disc With Integrated Updates](http://www.howtogeek.com/124368/how-to-create-a-customized-windows-7-installation-disc-with-integrated-updates/)

Both use [RT7Lite](http://www.rt7lite.com/) tool used for customization of Windows 7 images.

Comment: is it with this method also possible to pre-install photoshop etc?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly - Yes.

Comment: I wil give it a try!

Comment: this is not exactly what i want. Is it also possible to create an image of my currently running windows??

Comment: Check this > http://superuser.com/a/324001/155564